# Problema con tokens de OpenAi

Tags: python, procesamiento-de-texto, modelos

estoy creando una interfaz que me permita cargar un documento html, de tal manera que pueda interactuar con el realizando preguntas a través de LLM de OpenAi y usando embeddings de OpenAi, el problema que tengo es que a raíz de ya cargar mi html y generar la pregunta me genera que estoy usando mucho mas tokens de los que el modelo admite, como puedo solventar este problema, creo saber que el problema radica en la generación de los fragmentos de texto del documento, este es mi código:

```
import os

from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredHTMLLoader



 import streamlit as st


 os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'ApiKey'
 default_doc_name = 'doc.html'



 def process_doc(
    path: str = "C:\\Users\\Mateo\\Downloads\\Documento-de-examen-Grupo1.html",
    is_local: bool = False,
    question: str = 'Quiénes son los autores del pdf?'
 ):

_, loader = os.system(f'curl -o {default_doc_name} {path}'), UnstructuredHTMLLoader(f"./{default_doc_name}") if not is_local \
    else UnstructuredHTMLLoader(path)


doc = loader.load_and_split()


print(doc[-1])

db = Chroma.from_documents(doc, embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings())

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type='stuff', retriever=db.as_retriever())
st.write(qa.run(question))
print( "\n*** LA PREGUNTA ES:"+question, "\n****"+qa.run(question))


def client():
st.title('Manage LLM with LangChain')
uploader = st.file_uploader('Upload html', type='html')

if uploader:
    with open(f'./{default_doc_name}', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(uploader.getbuffer())
    st.success('HTML saved!!')

question = st.text_input('Generar un resumen de 20 palabras sobre el documento',
                         placeholder='Give response about your PDF', disabled=not uploader)

if st.button('Send Question'):
    if uploader:
        process_doc(
            path=default_doc_name,
            is_local=True,
            question=question
        )
    else:
        st.info('Loading default HTML')
        process_doc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
client()
#process_doc()
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de lo que hace tu código, pero chatgpt tiene un limite de tokens (un token es masomenos una palabra) para los mensajes. Si ese es el caso, tendrás que usar trucos, como reducir el tamaño de la pregunta, o del documento html (podés quitarle la indentación) etc